DC power out projects from laptop batteries
I am aware of existence of SMBus signals on the battery connector and the dialog between battery and computer, to supply and charge
However, I am only interested in the DC supply from the battery and I wish if there is any method to force the battery to just supply DC current through its plus and minus pins independently of the device using the battery.
From batteries pinout, I am curious about the purpose of these pins, because maybe they need an input:
Lenovo pin "ID"
Asus pin "ID"
Asus pin "Control"
Of course I always can open the battery case and connect from cell "bank" but it implies to break the plastic, and add a control circuit for safety

Is your assumption even valid? Why would there be no output from battery without some handshaking? My assumption is the complete opposite, you always get battery output from the high current terminals, through the internal BMS, so whatever you need is already there. The SMBus is generally just for asking the BMS about battery serial number, original capacity, current state of charge, estimated time of charging left, and remaining capacity due to it being used, etc.

My assumption was based in the checks done on 2batteries a Thinkpad 10.8V and ASUS EEE os also 10.8V . I will check more to ensure how common or not is the behavior.

There are multiple connections to a laptop battery. The + and - connections are pure DC. Other connections are used for charging cells separately, for measuring cell temperature, for battery identification, etc.
Though you'd still need to access the other pins of the connector for charging the battery, expect just the nominal DC output voltage on the power terminals.

Maybe in a new battery these pin connections offer output by default. And maybe here the control board disabled the output after detecting that the battery went below certain value. Assuming that this is true, a reset would be needed to re-enable the output.
